# SQL COALESCE modification

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have below code

```
SELECT @email = COALESCE(@email + ', ', '') + Email
FROM dbo.FTX_ALERTUSER WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE AlertID = 9017 AND Email IS NOT NULL

SELECT @email2 = VENDOREMAIL 
FROM FTX_NCMR_VENDOR_REQUIREMENT WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE VENDORCODE = @param1 AND BU = @param2

SELECT @email = @email + ',' + ISNULL(@email2,''' ''')
```

Which is creating string

```
[ftx_alert_list] 'updateLastRunDT','9017','FTX-Software, Karthik@XYZ.com, ray@XYZ.com, tony@XYZ.com, yen@XYZ.com,' '','FTX_F20160607004'
```

I want to correct this string like

```
[ftx_alert_list] 'updateLastRunDT','9017','FTX-Software, Karthik@XYZ.com, ray@XYZ.com, tony@XYZ.com, yen@XYZ.com','','FTX_F20160607004'`
```

The only difference is `,' '',` I want `','',` after yen@XYZ.com.

Comment: What is the exact output of `@email`  and `@email2` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar @email='FTX-Software, Karthik@XYZ.com, ray@XYZ.com, tony@XYZ.com, yen@XYZ.com,'

Comment: and for @email2= '',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change the last line as below. Using [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) you can get your expected characters only.

```
SELECT @email = '''' + SUBSTRING(@email, 0, LEN(@email)) + '''' + ',' + ISNULL(@email2,''' ''')
```

Sample execution with the given data.

```
DECLARE @FTX_ALERTUSER TABLE(Email VARCHAR (50));

INSERT INTO @FTX_ALERTUSER (Email) VALUES
('FTX-Software'), ('Karthik@XYZ.com'), ('ray@XYZ.com'), ('tony@XYZ.com'), ('yen@XYZ.com');

DECLARE @FTX_NCMR_VENDOR_REQUIREMENT TABLE (VENDOREMAIL VARCHAR (50));

INSERT INTO @FTX_NCMR_VENDOR_REQUIREMENT (VENDOREMAIL) VALUES (NULL);

DECLARE @email AS VARCHAR (MAX) = '';
DECLARE @email2 AS VARCHAR (MAX) = '';

SELECT @email = @email + COALESCE(Email + ', ', '') 
FROM @FTX_ALERTUSER

--SELECT @email

SELECT @email2 = VENDOREMAIL 
FROM @FTX_NCMR_VENDOR_REQUIREMENT 

--SELECT @email2

SELECT @email = '''' + SUBSTRING(@email, 0, LEN(@email)) + '''' + ',' + ISNULL(@email2, ''' ''')

SELECT @email
```